# Restore directory under ~/Library from TimeMachine

Tags: time-machine, catalina

I want to restore a directory from TimeMachine backup.

Unfortunately the folder I want to restore is under `~/Library` which is not shown when I enter TimeMachine.

It is simple enough to access `~/Library` but I can't figure how to do it in TimeMachine - any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a kludge, which enabled me to restore the file, although I am not entirely comfortable with this.

I added `~/Library` to the Sidebar, it then showed in TimeMachine.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is an alias (shortcut) to your home folder, within a macOS environment it refers to: `/Users/{username}`.

So for me it would be `/Users/tom/` and the Library folder would be `/Users/tom/Library`.

You can launch Time Machine, navigate to the time that you are looking for then using the shortcut you usually use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to get the "Go to folder:" dialog. Then use the above path format to navigate to the Library folder.

***Tip:*** You can autocomplete the path by pressing tab, in the above example if you alredy typed `/Us` and press <kbd>⇥</kbd> you'll get either `/Users` typed for you or a pop up with a list of options. This is useful when trying to figure out your username for the first time!

Answer (score 0):

To show invisible files and folders in Finder and in Time Machine, just press <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>. That will let you restore files in ~/Library and any other hidden folder.

Answer (score 0):

The Time Machine app is just like the Finder: everything you can do in Finder, you can do there. So whatever it is you do to get to the user Library in the Finder: do that in TM.

Also, the TM app normally opens to the Finder window that is in the foreground when you launch it. So if you have your user Library in a Finder window, and then launch the TM app from the menulet, you should be there.

Comment: Finder has a Menu - conspicuously absent from Time Machine (as is Help)

Comment: OK, but everything you can do in terms of navigating through windows.